# system.security.verificationexception for unit tests

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

Few of my unit tests are failing due to SecurityVerification exception. 
    system.security.verificationexception operation could destabilize the runtime

I am using VS2010 with .net 4.5 on my machine. I have changing SecurityRuleSet to Level1. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution for this?